# How do I separate the file explorer process from the desktop process?

Tags: windows, file, desktop, explorer

I noticed when using Windows that explorer.exe is file explorer AND the desktop! How do I make file explorer and the desktop run in different processes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following "folders options" in Windows : use a separate process for new windows, as described [in this link](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-start-file-explorer-in-a-separate-process-in-windows-10/).
As is, the windows explorer won't crash the desktop when busy.

Comment: desktop is indeed explorer.exe
file navigator as well.